Variance of Standard Deviation in Linear Regression
Consider the linear regression setup $$y=X\beta+\epsilon$$ with $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and thus $y|X\sim N(X,\sigma^2 I)$. Let $X$ be $n\times p$ and $Y$ be $n\times 1$.
I understand that an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ is $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{n-p}||y-X\hat{\beta}||_2^2$, and I am aware of some ways to show this, for example here.
Question: I am unsure what goes wrong in the approach I outline below to show that $\hat{\sigma}^2 = 1/n ||y-X\hat{\beta}||_2^2$ is an unbiased estimator. Would appreciate someone pointing out my mistake:
$$\mathbb{E}(||y-X\hat{\beta}||_2^2)=\mathbb{E}(\sum_{n} (y_i-\sum_p x_{ij} \beta_j)^2)$$
Then from the above distribution of $y|X$, we have that $y_i|X\sim N(\sum_p x_{ij} \beta_j,\sigma^2)$ and so this reduces by linearity to
$$\sum_n \mathbb{V}(y_i|X) = n\sigma^2$$
Thus one sees that $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{n} ||y-X\hat{\beta}||_2^2$ is an unbiased estimator. Where does the rank $p$ of $X$ come into play?

Welcome to CV, Derrick.  This is a FAQ that we refer to the [math.se] site because it's only about checking your algebra: you can find explicit answers in many threads here on CV.  Here's a useful focused search.
